# Background images don't show in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I currently have my background images set to:

```
#two {
        background:url(http://d7.gordongroup.com/NisgaFilmPitch/images/bgimg_3.jpg);
        background-size:cover;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        background-position:center center;
    }
```

I also have a big video in the Hero section. I cannot figure out why the images will not show sometimes and sometimes they will.

The website link is below: 
http://d7.gordongroup.com/NisgaFilmPitch/index.html

Please somebody save me from ripping my hair out. Thank you.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? I tested it in Chrome 39 and it works fine.

Comment: Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit). It's frustrating because it will work sometimes and then sometimes the images decide to not load properly.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the video in the Hero Section. When I take out the video it works seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Put quotations around your image URL

```
background:url("http://d7.gordongroup.com/NisgaFilmPitch/images/bgimg_3.jpg");
```